# Are these brown spots on back of drywall mold?

Tags: drywall

I've discovered brown spots that could be mold growth on the back of nearly all my drywall in the upstairs of my house. Both interior and exterior walls have it. The density of the spots is the same everywhere that I've tested.

The video is of a section I took out but I've inspected all the rooms in my upstairs with a pinhole camera and they all have these mysterious spots on them. I am wondering if the drywall had moisture before it was installed and never properly dried?

House was built in 1989 in southern California. Any ideas what this might be would be greatly appreciated.

My wife has been suffering with a severe sinus infection for several months and I suspect that this could be the cause. Thank you in advance!

[Video](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/z2n17tix11pr2b7piv5kk/drywall-brown-spots.mov?rlkey=fun1ztciz3uojg3wfppso162a&dl=0)

[image]

Comment: just looks like recycled paper fibers probably in 1989 the consistency of the paper fibers was less standardized than today's recycled brown you find on the back.  google image search drywall mold...   or backside of drywall and you'll see some similar to yours.

Comment: backside of drywall - https://reusellcvs.life/product_details/80629736.html , https://www.htmlcommentbox.com/storage/lg_16043227_pxl_20220908_225048554.jpg

Comment: The only way to be 100% certain if it's mold is to send it off to a lab to have it tested. If it is mold, then your wife can take the test results to her doctor and she can be tested to see if she's allergic to this particular type of mold. Not everything is mold, and not all molds are bad for humans. Also, if you've lived in the house significantly longer than her sinus infection, there's probably no causal relation between the two...

Comment: They don't look like "fibers" to me, but they certainly could be dye splotches from manufacturing. Do they rub off? Most mold smears easily. If so, does it _smell_ moldy?

Comment: The spots do not scrath off, no smell, and do not disappear with RMR 86 mold remover, so I am really hoping you are all right. I will have it tested ASAP

Comment: I did try googling "mold on the backside of drywall" and similar searches and could not find a single example that looks like mine, plus nothing that had the same consistency across the entire board. They were all more concentrated near the water damaged area and then dissipated with distance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the only way to tell for sure that it's (harmful) mold is to have a lab test it.